# how to get physical memory including reserved memory from linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, memory, kernel

From linux's proc.txt:

```
MemTotal: Total usable ram (i.e. physical ram minus a few reserved
```

But how to get the whole physical ram **including** reserved memory from linux kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
physpages = get_num_physpages();
```

```
pr_info("Memory: %luK/%luK available (%luK kernel code, %luK rwdata, %luK rodata, %luK init, %luK bss, %luK reserved, %luK cma-reserved"
#ifdef  CONFIG_HIGHMEM
        ", %luK highmem"
#endif
        "%s%s)\n",
        nr_free_pages() << (PAGE_SHIFT - 10),
        physpages << (PAGE_SHIFT - 10),
        codesize >> 10, datasize >> 10, rosize >> 10,
        (init_data_size + init_code_size) >> 10, bss_size >> 10,
        (physpages - totalram_pages() - totalcma_pages) << (PAGE_SHIFT - 10),
        totalcma_pages << (PAGE_SHIFT - 10),
#ifdef  CONFIG_HIGHMEM
        totalhigh_pages() << (PAGE_SHIFT - 10),
#endif
        str ? ", " : "", str ? str : "");
```

So `get_num_physpages << (PAGE_SHIFT - 10)` will get the whole physical memory.